# How to implement this multiple select and where query with Hibernate criteria?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have faced a Hibernate criteria query issues.

Table `DataStatus` data looks like below:

```
|-------------|--------------|--------------|---------------------|
|     name    |     info     |    server    |      starttime      |
|-------------|--------------|--------------|---------------------|
|     Bob     | information1 |     www1     | 2018-02-14 10:32:43 |
|     Alice   | information2 |     www3     | 2018-02-14 17:34:43 |
|     Bob     | information3 |     www2     | 2018-02-14 10:32:43 |
|     Alice   | information4 |     www1     | 2018-02-14 11:25:51 |
|     Alice   | information5 |     www2     | 2018-02-14 08:42:25 |
|     Bob     | information6 |     www3     | 2018-02-14 10:32:43 |
|-------------|--------------|--------------|---------------------|
```

Query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM DataStatus sts 
WHERE sts.server IS NOT NULL 
AND sts.name = 'Bob' 
AND sts.starttime < (
   SELECT starttime FROM DataStatus 
   WHERE name = 'Alice' AND server = sts.server);
```

And the result looks like this:

```
|-------------|--------------|--------------|---------------------|
|     name    |     info     |    server    |      starttime      |
|-------------|--------------|--------------|---------------------|
|     Bob     | information1 |     www1     | 2018-02-14 10:32:43 |
|     Bob     | information6 |     www3     | 2018-02-14 10:32:43 |
|-------------|--------------|--------------|---------------------|
```

I have tried something like below:

```
Criteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria(DataStatus.class);
criteria.add(
    Restrictions.and(
        criteria.add(Restrictions.isNotNull("server")),
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("name", "Bob")),
        criteria.add(Restrictions.lt("starttime", ))
    )
);
```

I have no idea how to implement this nested where and select query with Hibernate criteria?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that sql query is valid, I suspect it would return an error saying sub query returns more tha one row or something similar

Comment: Hi @JoakimDanielson, I'm quite sure SQL is right. It's returning the right data for me.

Comment: @Almett your query returns only 1 row: `"Bob" "information1" "www1" "2018-02-14 10:32:43"`. Maybe the data you posted is not the actual data. Also in your query change `'ALice'` to `'Alice'`, unless it's a typo or the equality is not case-sensitive.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, it's 'Alice' not 'ALice'. I have changed the `starttime` of Alice(www3) to make it bigger than Bob(www3)'s 'starttime'. Now it returns the same result as mine. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Assuming (name, server) is unique OP will be ok, if not.. trouble may arise!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My advice is to keep trying, look more in the Javadocs, experiment in your IDE. And if you give up, try the below (assuming your table is modeled in class `DataStatus`):

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<DataStatus> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(DataStatus.class);
Root<DataStatus> root = criteriaQuery.from(DataStatus.class);

Subquery<Date> subquery = criteriaQuery.subquery(Date.class);
Root<DataStatus> innerRoot = subquery.from(DataStatus.class);

subquery.select(innerRoot.get("startTime"))
        .where(criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.equal(innerRoot.get("name"), "Alice"),
                criteriaBuilder.equal(innerRoot.get("server"), root.get("server"))));

criteriaQuery.select(root).where(
        criteriaBuilder.and( criteriaBuilder.isNotNull( root.get( "server" ) ),
                criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("name"), "Bob" ),
                criteriaBuilder.lessThan(root.<Date> get("startTime"), subquery)

        ) );

Query<DataStatus> query = session.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
List<DataStatus> resultList = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: This code is working perfectly. Gorgeous one! Bravo! Thank you very much.

Comment: But it only works with Hibernate-5.2+ though. And the `createCriteria()` method is deprecated in Hibernate-5.2+. If there're bunch of criteria are written in `createCriteria()` should be refactored. Great answer anyways.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with Hibernate, but you can rewrite the query to avoid the subselect

```
   SELECT bob.* /** Only include cols from Bob records */
     FROM DataStatus bob 

          /** Only include rows with a later Alice record on the same server */   
     JOIN DataStatus alice
       ON alice.name = 'Alice'
      AND alice.server = bob.server
      AND alice.starttime > bob.starttime

    WHERE bob.name = 'Bob'
```

You may find this plays nicer with the Hibernate syntax

**N.B.** This assumes that you have a maximum of one record per name and server. This could be enforced by a UNIQUE KEY on (name,server)

This assumption is based on the condition `WHERE {bob server row starttime} < SELECT {alice server row starttime}`from your original query, which doesn't really make sense if the SELECT can return more than one row

Comment: Hi @Arth, Thank for the great effort. Yes, it works with Hibernate syntax but my project requirement was to use Hibernate Criteria. Your deep thought on this issue looks very impressive, I'll try to redesign the SQL with your tip. Thanks!

Comment: @Almett Happy to help! I meant that this may play nicer with the Hibernate Criteria. From my experience with PHP frameworks, JOINs appear to be better supported than subqueries. That being said, this was only meant to be a supplement to a more involved answer, but was too rich for a comment!